# function not applying on all divs with same class

Tags: jquery, function, html, slideshow

I have created a slideshow for images contained in a div with class called "mainSlide", this works perfectly but when i attempt to create another div with the same class name "mainSlide", i dont see any slideshow effect on the second div just the first one.

```
<div class="mainSlide">
<img src="img/1.jpg" style="display:none;" />
<img src="img/2.jpg" style="display:none;" />
<img src="img/3.jpg" style="display:none;" />
</div>
<br /><br /><br/><br />

<div class="mainSlide">
<img src="img/1.jpg" style="display:none;" />
<img src="img/2.jpg" style="display:none;" />
<img src="img/3.jpg" style="display:none;" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

slideShow();

function slideShow() {
    $allSlides = $('div.mainSlide img').length;
    $hiddenSlides = $('div.mainSlide img:hidden').length;

    if ($hiddenSlides == $allSlides) {
        $('div.mainSlide img:first').fadeToggle('slow', function() { slideShow(); });
    } else {
        $('div.mainSlide').find('img:visible').delay(5000).fadeToggle('slow', 
            function() {
                if ($(this).attr('src')==$('div.mainSlide img:last').attr('src')) {
                    $('div.mainSlide img:first').fadeToggle('slow', function() { slideShow(); });
                } else {
                    $(this).next('img').fadeToggle('slow', function() {slideShow();});
                }
            });
    }
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: You're code does'nt magically work with more instantiations. Easiest would be to use a variable in place of the main element, and call the slideshow on each() .mainSlide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is written under the assumption that there will only be one slide show.

To handle multiple slide shows you have to loop through the `mainSlide` elements, and do everything in the `slideShow` function on each one. Also, you have to use each `mainSlide` element as scope when you handle the images, so that the code only applies to the images in that element.

```
$('div.mainSlide').each(function(i, slide){
  slideShow(slide);
});

function slideShow(slide) {

  $allSlides = $('img', slide).length;

  // and so on...

}
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa, im a beginner in jquery, so if you dont mind asking, i dont get what you mean by slide in function(i, slide) because i tried to fetch the value of it and i got  [object HTMLDivElement] so i dont think that will relate to the images under the div. you mind explaining more please! or did you mean $('div.mainSlide img').each

Comment: @Maz: The `slide` parameter will be a reference to the DOM element for each `mainSlide` element. You want to loop through the `mainSlide` elements to handle the image elements inside it as a group, not all the image elements directly, otherwise you will still only have one slideshow.